# Automate filing an encrypted PDF form with python

Tags: python, pdf, encryption, adobe, acrobat

I have to submit a large set of PDF files to a government agency which has encrypted the template. The file is protected from editing but not from filing the form.

Is there a means of using python to fill the form without access to the encryption password?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi. StackOverflow really isn't for this kind of "what's good software to help me" question, but [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is. Please post this question over there. I've wrestled with this myself, submitting Emergency Rental Assistance applications, and I might be able to help.